# What countries don't have fair use in copyright law?

Tags: copyright, international, fair-use

I know that Japan is one of these countries without fair use, are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fair Use only exists in the USA

Fair use is a **very** specific doctrine. [It only exists in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)A. [Many other countries have other exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limitations_and_exceptions_to_copyright). Some are similar, but almost none are identical. In fact, most are *substantially* different

- In the UK, there is "[Fair Dealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing)", which is in some parts extremely narrow.
- Germany has an exception for "Teaching and research", criticism, and comment, but is **much** more narrow.